# Android: Changing extras to an intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, extras

I have an app that goes between many different activities.  One activity, my main activity, has it's behavior dependent on which activity, within the app, launched the main activity.  I thought i could log this by having every other activity put an extra called "launcehdFrom" into the intent, which contains a string that has the name of hte activity that called the main activity.  The problem i ran into is that once that value has been set it can't be overriden by another activity.  I havne't found a good straightforward method for doing this.  Any advice??

The following code is called from onResume() in my main activity:

```
    private void processIntentRequest(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ProcessIntentRequestType caller = (ProcessIntentRequestType)intent.getSerializableExtra("launchedFrom");
    switch(caller){
        case startUpActivity:
            load(this.myObj);
            break;

        case otherActivity:
            int uri = integer.parseInt(this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("uri"));          
            load(this.myObj, uri);
            break;

        default:
            load(this.myObj, 1);
    }
```

This is the code that launches the main activity the first time:

```
public void launchMainActivity(Obj myObj){
    Intent launchMain = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);
    login.putExtra("launchedFrom", ProcessIntentRequestType.startupActivity);
    startActivity(launchMain);
}
```

This is the code that launches the main activity from some other activity after it has been loaded atleast once by the startup activity:

```
protected void launchMainActivity(Obj myObj, HelperObj helper) {
    String uri = helper.uri;
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    mainActivity.putExtra("uri", uri);
    mainActivityputExtra("launchedFrom", ProcessIntentRequestType.otherActivity);
    startActivity(mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to set the string from the intent?

Comment: the code is up now.  It's not actually a string, because you can't use switch on a string.  It's an enum that represents a string.  I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP when calling startActivity which has some notable behavior. In this case, override [`onNewIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) and call `setIntent` from there. After that, the platform will call `onResume` and your call to `getIntent` will return the new intent.